# How to open the "Problems" view in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

I recently installed the Arctic Fox update of Android Studio on Catalina macOs, and I'm not able to find the "problems" view in the project overview scroll options, does anyone have any idea about it?

The exact build is:
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 1.
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7621141, built on August 7, 2021

[image]

Edit: Actually I found it in the bottom of the tool window bar using the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should ask the IDE itself, instead of taking to the internet:

- click `Help` > `Find Action` ...or use the shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
- then type eg. `problems`
- click the result.

Comment: Thank you @Martin, your solution is the most adequate. the shortcut is Command + Shift + A for the mac users.

Answer (score 1):

It should be on the Left Bottom Corner as illustrated below.

[image]

If not go to `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Problems` to reveal it - see the below illustration though from Windows OS but AS on Windows is similar to Mac.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Tonnie, I found it just after posting by chance with the Command+E shortcut, your solution is helpful though.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it under View menu option.[image]